# Why isn't the body of my message being sent in drupal_mail()?

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-forms

I'm very new drupal forms but have managed to set up a `drupal_mail` function that upon submit sends an email to the desired location with the correct `$subject` message and `$from` email address. It is not, however, sending the body of the message. I've googled/tried a lot of things but nothing seems to grab the correct value. Can anybody see why? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
function drupalform_menu() {
$items['drupalform/form1'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments'=>array('drupalform_form1'));

  return $items;
} ?>


<?php function drupalform_form1() {
$form = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div id="contact-form" class="row section"><div 
class="container">',
    '#suffix' => '</div></div>',
); ?>


   <?php $form['name']=array(
    '#prefix' => '<div class="col l5 s12">',
    '#type'=>'textfield',
    '#title'=>t('FIRST & LAST NAME'),
  ); ?>

<?php $form['email']=array(
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#type'=>'textfield',
    '#title'=>t('EMAIL'),
  ); ?>

 <?php $form['message']=array(
    '#prefix' => '<div id="form-message" class="col l5 push-l1 s12 ">',
    '#type'=>'textarea',
    '#title'=>t('MESSAGE'),
  ); ?>

<?php $form['submit']=array(
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#type'=>'submit',
    '#value'=>t('SEND MESSAGE')
  );

  return $form; ?>


<?php } ?>


<?php

function drupalform_form1_submit($form, $form_state) {
$to = "test@test.com";
$from = "sender@sender.com";
$subject = "New message from the Louisville Digital Inclusion Site";
$body = $form_state['values']['message'];


$params = array(
    'subject' => $subject,
    'body' => $body,
    );

drupal_mail('test', 'information', $to, language_default(), $params, $from);

drupal_set_message("Form has been submitted");
}


function test_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
switch ($key) {
case 'information':
  $message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
  $message['body'] = $params['body'];
break;
}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it figured out! I had to change my `test_mail` function to read as follows:

```
function test_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
switch ($key) {
case 'information':
$message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
$message['body'][] = $params['body'];
break;
}
}
```

I needed to add empty brackets after `$message['body'][] = $params['body']`.